# Create another SSH key for the same user

Tags: ssh

At the moment, there is a user with username "userA" with it's own RSA SSH key, let's call it "KeyA1".

How do I add another RSA SSH key to that same user "userA", "KeyA2"?

So that "userA" can SSH to the server with either of the key.
And let's say one day I want to delete "KeyA2", "KeyA1" is still usable or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

To expand/clarify on Kiwy's answer, ssh provides the ability to use different private keys using the -i _identity_file_ option.  The identity file is the private key file, not the public key file in the ssh-copy-id command given by Kiwy.  The ssh-copy-id command should be

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa2 name@host
```

To use ssh with KeyA1, the user can run

```
ssh name@host
```

or

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa name@host
```

To use keyA2, the user must use

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa2 name@host
```

Comment: I handle having multiple keys by using `ssh-agent`. It can also cache passwords for keys. None of this `-i named-key` awkwardness.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a new key:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f .ssh/id_rsa2
```

Copy the key to your remote host:

```
ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa2.pub name@host
```

Et voilà

Comment: The public key needs to be added to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, not just copied to the `.ssh` directory.

Comment: @DougO'Neal what you mean ? ssh-copy-id is copying id_rsa2.pub to the remote host authorized_keys